# PGP Encryption in Mule keeps failing with NullPointerException

Tags: java, encryption, mule, mule-studio, pgp

I have been attempting to encrypt a text file with the PGP encryptor in my Mule flow and have so far been unsuccessful. I am executing against the CloudHub Mule Runtime (Dec 2013) as I intend to deploy to CloudHub.

I have used GnuPG to generate the binary public key from the .asc file provided to me by my client and put the resulting .gpg file in my src/main/resources directory. Even though it doesn't seem like I should have to I generated my own secret gpg keyring and provided that in my application as well.

When I attempt to run my flow it keeps giving me an NPE:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.module.pgp.KeyBasedEncryptionStrategy.checkKeyExpirity(KeyBasedEncryptionStrategy.java:100)
    at org.mule.module.pgp.KeyBasedEncryptionStrategy.safeGetCryptInfo(KeyBasedEncryptionStrategy.java:87)
    at org.mule.module.pgp.KeyBasedEncryptionStrategy.encrypt(KeyBasedEncryptionStrategy.java:54)
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I've updated to use the latest version of AnyPoint Studio with the 3.5.1 runtime and get the same error,  on line 98 this time which is the same line of code.

**UPDATE AND *MY SOLUTION*:**

I got it to work. It was an error on my part. I had a principal in the Encryption element that was overriding the principal from the Global element. I had placed this principal in the configuration to overcome an initial error telling me it was required. Removing this principal seems to have resolved all of my problems.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

I can successfully encrypt using the pub and sec keys provided in a Mule blog post, however, attempting to use the gpg file that I exported from the public key (.asc file) that my client provided but I again get the NPE mentioned above. I have followed all the steps I can find for importing their key into my keyring and exporting it as a binary. I'm stumped.

**FINAL UPDATE**

So it turns out the success with the keys from the [Mule blog](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/pgp-encryption-and-salesforce-integration-using-mulesoft%E2%80%99s-anypoint-platform/) were giving me a success that I didn't completely understand. Turns out that I was not properly setting the **Principal** value. I was setting the principal according to what I thought it should be for the secret keyring, when, as I found out, it is actually for the public key ring. All seems to be working now.

Comment: Which version of mule would that be?

Comment: Added the runtime to the entry. (CloudHub Mule Runtime 2013)

Comment: Next time show your config: showing a stacktrace only is not enough.

Comment: Good point, as it turns out I'm still having issues, but my investigation seems to indicate it's an issue with the public key my client provided. I got a public ".asc" file from them, I use GnuPG to import it and export it as binary and place the resulting ".gpg" file in src/main/resources but the error still occurs trying to retrieve the public key resulting in the same NPE as above. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: I can't get it to work with any of the keys I generate myself. I'm on a new Macbook, using GPG Keychain Access. Any key I export and use causes the error. Suggestions?